# CakePHP 2.3.0 component $controller is not accessible

Tags: cakephp, components, cakephp-2.0

I am using Cakephp 2.3.0, loading following component.

```
class BreadCrumbsComponent extends Component {

public $components = array();
public $controller = null;

public function initialize($controller) {

}

public function startup($controller) {
    $this->controller = $controller;
}

public function beforeRender($controller) {

}

public function shutDown($controller) {

}

public function beforeRedirect($controller, $url, $status = null, $exit = true) {

}

public function handle($controllerName = NULL, $actionName = NULL) {
    pr($this->controller->modelClass);
}
```

}

It get error following error

```
Trying to get property of non-object [APP\Controller\Component\BreadCrumbsComponent.php, line 38]
```

I am unable to access $this->controller there. Any reason? How do I make it work?

Comment: Did you verify that startup() is being triggered? It should be if you properly initiated your component as the documentation explains it. So since this is most likely the issue you should also post the relevant controller code here.

Comment: Try to initialize your controller in `initialize` method.

Comment: @mark yes startup() is working

Comment: @MubasshirPawle - Great !! I posted as answer to help future visitors :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Read [here](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers/components.html#Component%3a%3astartup) *startup* method is called after the controller so need to initialize controller in *initialize* method as below,

```
public function initialize(&$controller, $settings = array()) {
    $this->controller = $controller;
}
```

Comment: startup() usually also works - IF the handle() method is not used in beforeFilter methods, but in the actions itself. It seems that this is not the case here. so your solution is the best one :)